# How to open website with https only?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I had developed website in Magento 2.3 but by default it is coming with http only and now my requirement is by default it has to open with https only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to Admin Panel => Stores => Settings => Configuration => General => Web
2. Update Base URL and Base Secure URL to the https version. E.g. https://screencast.com/t/bTYqhe6Ymi